# resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40566318...in android listview

Tags: android, hashmap

this error apear when i add bitmap image in hashmap to display it in listview
any help please??

```
         hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put(IMAGE, ops);
            hm.put(TITLE, text);
            hm.put(CARDS_COUNT, cardsCount +" Stampii");
            items.add(hm);
    }

    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.main_listview,
            new String[]{TITLE, CARDS_COUNT, IMAGE}, new int[]{ R.id.main_name, R.id.main_info, R.id.main_img});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as you are adding the `Bitmap` object to the map, but what you should add is a uri that points to the bitmap (e.g. a file uri, a content uri, ...) not the bitmap it self. You can also add an integer resource id (e.g. R.drawable.my_bitmap).

Comment: i got image url from json and convert it to bimap but i can`t display it

Comment: Just put the url as a string in the map and see if that helps.

Comment: Looking further at this I think that it could be a good idea for you to implement a [SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html) to do the binding for you. There you could use an async task to load the bitmap and set it. If you don't it may be the case that you download the bitmap on the main thread. You have to test to find out :)